# Angular momenta of closed bosonic string

Tags: angular-momentum, string-theory

Say we have the standard mode expansion of the closed bosonic string in conformal gauge. We compute the angular momenta which has an integration over the co-ordinate along the string.
We get a zero-mode part which is like the 'particle' angular momenta, and then there is the contribution from the oscillatory pieces. The answer has a piece involving only left moving modes, and another piece involving only the right moving modes.

What is the physical intuition which can explain why the cross term between the right and left moving modes gets integrated to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition is that the left and right movers are constrained to move "as an unique object" by the level matching condition. More precisely, **the left and right Virasoro oscillators are not independent of each other, instead they are related to each other by means of the level matching condition.**

Any term in the expansion of the angular momentum for a closed string that is a product of left and right movers oscillators can be made into a product of only left or right mover oscillators by writing one set of oscillators (say the right ones) in terms of the other (say the left ones).

To understand the importance of the level matching condition for the dynamics of a closed relativistic string, see: [Closed strings and the level matching condition](http://theoreticalminimum.com/courses/string-theory-and-m-theory/2010/fall/lecture-4).

Comment: I know about the level matching condition in closed bosonic string theory, but I don't see how we can explicitly use that to write a single right moving mode entirely in terms of left moving modes.